# How to use .htaccess mod rewrite to redirect php url as a string?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've been trying to make:

```
http://site.com/file.php?x=foo
```

redirect to:

```
http://newsite.com/something/completely/different/
```

Using the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^file\.php?x=foo$ http://newsite.com/something/completely/different/ [R=301,NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't do anything (just loads same old page as if I never touched the htaccess).

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` at the end of `.php` is making the last `p` optional (so `.phpx=foo` or `.phx=foo` would match). It's not actually being considered a character in the match. Try escaping the `?` like: `\?`

**Edit**:

For those wondering what the solution was:

The query string arguments aren't passed to the string that `RewriteRule` matches against. So you have to create a `RewriteCond` on `QUERY_STRING` first, then match the url without arguments. E.g.:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} x=foo
RewriteRule ^file\.php$ http://newsite.com/something/completely/different/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

There's probably/hopefully a better way to do this (since this `RewriteCond` would cascade down to other rules, which is annoying).

Comment: I tried: RewriteRule ^file\.php\?x=foo$ but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Nuke the `^` anchor in the front and see if that works. I can't remember which part of the URL mod_rewrite starts matching at. It might be expecting `^/file...`

Comment: Nope, that was a no-go also. (neither deleting the ^ nor changing it to ^/file... worked)

Comment: Are you familiar with vhosts? Are you hitting `default` and do you know if `AllowOverride` is set properly?

Comment: Also, you can try removing the `IfModule` tags and see if you get an Error 500 - which would indicate mod_rewrite is not enabled

Comment: I have never heard of vhosts.  I do know that simple htaccess modrewrite is working on the same file: RewriteRule ^somefile.php$ http://site.com/newfile.php [R=301,NC,L]  so htaccess *is* enabled properly if that's what you're checking?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10677/discussion-between-jay-and-matt)

Comment: Also, just to note that if you didn't want to pass anything from the original query_string to the new url, you have to add "query string discard" flag: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/